# Интерактивная задача на угадывание числа. C++

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Условие [задачи](https://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=1&id_section=3&id_topic=37&id_problem=1131):

> Это интерактивная задача.
>
> Программа жюри загадывает целое число N (1 ≤ N ≤ 10^9), которое ваша
> программа должна будет отгадать не более чем за 100 попыток. Вы можете
> делать запросы путем вывода числа из возможного диапазона целых чисел.
> В ответ на каждый запрос программа жюри будет сообщать результат
> сравнения загаданного числа с числом в запросе.
>
> Протокол взаимодействия После каждого запроса целого числа X вашей
> программе будет сообщено в новой строке результат сравнения вашего
> числа X с загаданным числом N, что выражается выводом одного символа с
> переносом строки:
>
> "<" : загаданное число строго меньше числа в запросе (N < X);
>
> ">" : загаданное число строго больше числа в запросе (N > X);
>
> "=" : загаданное число совпадает с числом в запросе (N = X), при получении такого ответа ваша программа должна немедленно завершиться.
>
> Ваша программа должна произвести не больше 100 запросов.

Я думаю понятно, что тут нужно использовать бинарный поиск.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long l = 1, r = 10e9, mid = (l + r) / 2;
    while (true)
    {
        char input;
        mid = (l + r) / 2;
        cout << mid << endl;
        cin >> input;
        if (input == '>')
            l = mid + 1;
        else if (input == '<')
            r = mid - 1;
        else if(input == '=')
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Программа не проходит по времени. Значит где-то "застревает"? Но где? И почему? По идее все должно работать нормально...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все работает, просто берите не 10<sup>10</sup> в качестве максимального значения, а 10<sup>9</sup> -

```
r = 1e9;
```

Но еще лучше - не мелочитесь, не заставляйте преобразовывать `double` в `int` - пишите как есть:

```
r = 1'000'000'000;
```

Ну, или если компилятор этого не понимает (у ACMP - понимает :)), то

```
r = 1000000000;
```

P.S. Вероятно, тестирующая система работает с `int`, и ваше первое предложение 5000000000 воспринимает как 705032704, что и приводит к непоняткам и зацикливанию при числе от указанного до миллиарда...

Comment: Можете объяснить, пожалуйста, почему лучше сразу писать в `int`? Это чем-то чревато?

Comment: Не понял вопрос. Я писал о том, что проверяющая система работает с `int` (вероятно), и тогда все поясняется записью числа, превосходящего максимально возможное значение `int`, в переменную типа `int` ведет к проблемам.

Comment: Я насчет этого - "Но еще лучше - не мелочитесь, не заставляйте преобразовывать double в int - пишите как есть."

Comment: Ну, я всегда с подозрением отношусь к преобразованиям `int <-> double` в плане потери точности...

Answer (score 1):

Зачем столько лишнего? Я бы сделал так:

```
unsigned r = 1000000001, mid = r / 2, l = 1;
cout << mid;
char input{};
while ( cin >> input && input != '=')
{        
    if (input == '>')
        l = mid;
    else  
        r = mid;
    mid = (l + r) / 2;

    cout << mid;
}
return 0;
```

Во первых два миллиарда   вполне вмещается в `unsigned int`, во вторых, вы выводите ответ и вводите символ, который может иметь три значения, если не равно, значит меньше или больше.